# In Thesis List of Figures Problem

Tags: table-of-contents, templates, thesis

I have a problem I can't deal with.

I use this template for my thesis. I can't set the subfigures in the figure list as I am a beginner in using latex.

https://github.com/ondes/Template-Latex-ITU-Thesis/blob/master/Template-Thesis/thesis_itu.cls

The code below is a code from the cls file.

```
\renewcommand\listoffigures{% 
    %\vspace*{\ChapterUstenBosluk}              % This is not effective -
    {\chapter*{\listfigurename}%
    \vspace*{-18pt}%
    \renewcommand{\ULdepth}{4pt}%                 Added using ulem package for \uline command 
    \renewcommand{\ULthickness}{1.5pt}%     Added for underline tickness change which was 0.4pt 
    \if@Ingilizce\hfill\vspace*{0truecm}{\bf\uline{Page}}~\else~\hfill\vspace*{0truecm}{\bf\uline{Sayfa}}\fi}\\ % Instead of \underline{text} 
    %\hfill\vspace*{0.5truecm}{\bf\underline{\if@Ingilizce Page\else Sayfa\fi}}}

    \let\orig@numberline\numberline
    \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
    \renewcommand*{\numberline}[1]{%
    \orig@numberline{\bf\figurename\ ##1}\hspace{-8pt}{\bf:}\hspace{4pt}}%  Better spacing 
    \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\bf{\protect\listfigurenameToC}}%
    \setlength{\th@oldparskip}{\parskip}%
    \setlength{\parskip}{\LoFparskip}%
    \@starttoc{lof}%
    \setlength{\parskip}{\th@oldparskip}%
    \let\numberline\orig@numberline
    }
```

Here is the code I used to add subfigure.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  % include first image
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{Figures2/rc_final5.jpg}  
  \caption{Patch panel}
  \label{fig:sub-first}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  % include second image
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{Figures2/rc_final6.jpg}  
  \caption{Honeycomb ventilation gap}
  \label{fig:sub-second}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  % include second image
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{Figures2/rc_final9.jpg}  
  \caption{I-profiles}
  \label{fig:sub-second}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  % include second image
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{Figures2/rc_final11.jpg}  
  \caption{Power filter}
  \label{fig:sub-second}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Some details of RC prototype}
\label{fig:rc_details}
\end{figure}
```

Here is the image in pdf.

[image]

So far, so good. But the writings in the figure list are mixed.

[image]

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

Use  `\nextsubcaption` for the captions of the subfigures.

[image: b]

The command `\nextsubcaption` is defined by `thesis_itu.cls`.

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        % include first image
        \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image}  
        \nextsubcaption{Patch panel} % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \label{fig:sub-first}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        % include next image
        \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image}  
        \nextsubcaption{Honeycomb ventilation gap} % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \label{fig:sub-second}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        % include next image
        \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image}  
        \nextsubcaption{I-profiles} % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \label{fig:sub-second}
    \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        % include next image
        \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{example-image}  
        \nextsubcaption{Power filter} % changed <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        \label{fig:sub-second}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Some details of RC prototype}
    \label{fig:rc_details}
\end{figure}
```